# Why Redhat is not installing using HTTP

Tags: rhel, system-installation, http

Im trying to install Rehdat using HTTP and these are the steps I preformed to do it.

1. I copied the iso image in /var/www/rhel/5.9/
2. Then i made a HTTP YUM repo under /yum-repo.d/rhel-5.9.repo/Server

Contents of rhel-5.9.repo

```
[rhel-5.9.repo]
name = Redhat 5.9 HTTP repo
baseurl=http://localhost/rhel/5.9/installmedia/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

3.Run YUM REPO LIST
  4.I'm installing Redhat using Virtual Box. And both Server and Client are on same subnet
  5.And when I start the installation and after skipping Test the Media Dialog Box I eject the Media. And installation stops.

What Im doing wrong here.

Comment: How did you make and config that http yum repo? Have you tried that repo for an already-installed system? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I installed packages using the same repo. But Now I want to install Entire OS using http but ain't working.

Comment: Your `baseurl` is localhost - which means the machine being installed is trying to get the installation source from itself. Are you using interactive mode or kickstart to do the install?

Comment: Yes, Because this is the Source Server and iso image is mounted on this server. And Im trying to use this Source Server to install another Server.